# How to get href url if href contains in div tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get  href url if href attribute contains in anchor tag in div tag

```
<div id="testing">
<a onclick="http://google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>
<a onclick="http://gmail.com">gmail</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what you have tried. There are several ways to target the links depending on use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll collect this information

```
// .eq( idx ) will give you the element at index idx (this begins from 0)
var $second_a_tag = $('#testing a').eq(1);

// .attr( attr_name ) will give you the value of attr_name attribute.
var href_attribute = $second_a_tag.attr('href');
```

And you can for sure combine those lines if you don't care of keeping the `$second_a_tag` variable:

```
var href_attribute = $('#testing a').eq(1).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eq()` to get a specific element by index from a set:

```
$('#testing a').eq(1);
```

Or

```
$('#testing a:eq(1)');
```

Will both return the second `a` element - the link to `facebook.com` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Another options to get the anchor

1) `$("#testing a")[1].href`

2) `$("#testing a").eq(1).attr("href")`

3) By attribute selector

```js
 $("#testing a[href='http://facebook.com']").attr("href");
```

4) This one without jQuery

```js
document.getElementById("testing").getElementsByTagName("a")[1].href
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery `prop()` and `eq()`:

```
$('a:eq(1)', $('#testing')).prop('href'); //<-- http://facebook.com
```

or

```
$('a', $('#testing')).eq(1).prop('href'); //<-- http://facebook.com
```

or

```
$('#testing').find('a').eq(1).prop('href'); //<-- http://facebook.com
```

or

```
$('#testing').find('a:eq(1)').prop('href'); //<-- http://facebook.com
```